# Why is my conditional Render.memo not working? Is my code bad?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a simple counter screen that conditionally renders (something like shouldComponentUpdate) a counter component dependent on whether it is odd or even, it keeps rendering regardless of type of number. what am I doing wrong?

```
const Count = React.memo(({count}) => {
    return (<Text>{count}</Text>)
}, 

(oldProp, newProp) => {
    return(newProp.count % 2 === 0)
})

export default function App () {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const int = setInterval(() => {
        setCount(count + 1)
        }, 1000)
    
    return () => {clearInterval(int)} 
  
    }, [count])
  
    return (
        <View>
          <Count count={count}/>
        </View>
)}
```

Comment: React.memo(({count}) => {
    return (<Text>{count}</Text>)
}, [count])
Can you also check whether your component is Remounting or updating on prop change?

Comment: I copy pasted your code, and it's working fine. It shows 0, then 1, then 3 and so on.

Comment: @Mangesh React.memo doesn't take dependency array; it takes a function.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar I just realized it works perfectly, I was just impatient, thank you.